# How to default/config git log -n param?

Tags: git

I want to setup "git log" default params because it gives me too much information by default.

Basically, I want to type "git log" but I want to see "git log -n 5"

Do we have a way to do this? (without using alias, because I don't want to "git lg" instead of "git log")

ps. I expect the answer will be something like "git config log.count 5"

ps2. I managed to default the format with 
git config format.pretty "format:%h-%an : %s"

Comment: So , you want git log  to do the job of "git log -n 5"?

Comment: Yes, because typing "git log -5" everytime is not fun and I normally don't want to see anything more than top 5 commits anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a config option for that argument. You'll have to use an alias.

Comment: I wish this is not the correct answer. I'll leave it open for a bit longer just in case but looking at your profile make me feel like I should just mark this answer correct.

Comment: Still wonder why they think it's a good idea for git log to spit out 200+ commit logs by default (and fill the whole screen) instead of X logs (configurable) and if user want all log (to process by external program), he could use "git log -all" instead.

Comment: Thanks @mipadi for confirming , yes dekhadmai I was almost sure that this is the answer , but was not tooo sure to say it.

Comment: @NullSoulException I spent about 3 hours googling how to do this and can't find it so I gave up and try asking StackOverflow as my last resort. Also, thanks for the confirmation.